# Overhead of list() on a list

Tags: python, list

In certain styles of python, everything is a generator, e.g. uses `yield` rather than constructing and `return`ing a list. If you need to use it as a list, you can just call `list(gen)`.

If I have a list already, what is the cost of calling `list(my_list)`?

Use: I have a variable that I know has an iterator and *might* be a list, but I need to use it as a list. Is it better/more pythonic to do `my_list = list(my_list)` or some other way of checking its list-ness?

If it matters I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: If you call `list(x)` you are certainly creating a new list (even if `x` is a list). You can easily check `if isinstance(x, list)` to see if it is already a list or not.

Comment: please give an example of input & output

Comment: @khelwood I'd consider this comment an answer; format and post it as such and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You can use `timeit` to see how expensive it is. On my low power notebook, `list(my_list)` on a 10000 member list was 0.000187 seconds. Calling `isinstance` was way faster at 0.000000277. But its still trivial unless you are doing it a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `list(x)` you are certainly creating a new list, even if `x` is already a list. If you want to avoid it, you can use `isinstance(x, list)` to check if `x` is a list or not.

```
if not isinstance(x, list):
    x = list(x)
```

Comment: Definitely the right answer! Could alternatively do `x = list(x) if not isinstance(x, list) else x` if that's your jam

Comment: alternatively you can do a [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) check if can accept similar list-like object like tuple/str (immutable) or [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: @Copperfield This probably is the most complete, doing `x = list(x) if not isinstance(x, Sequence) else x`, as most likely if you need a list not a generator, what you really want is the `Sequence`-ness, not necessarily the `list`-ness.

Comment: @CAD97 yes, and if you do some change in `x`, then use instead `isinstance(x,MutableSequence)`